# Why can't css3 transition do more than one thing at the same time? With fiddle

Tags: css

I am trying to do a simple effect:

Div has an image and text with `RGBA(255,255,255,0.5)` background over it.

On hover I want to make the image lower opacity + background of text dissapear all in one smooth transition.

It all works as expected, except when I try to give both the img and text a transition, and instead of both things transitioning, the image lowers its opacity with a transition, but the text's background doesn't.

Any ideas why this is happening?

**UPDATE**: Tested it on firefox and it works fine. The problem appears to be to Chrome on Windows (I'm using the latest version), can anyone else with chrome/windows let me know if they see the problem too?

You can see a [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/rCf3k/)

Comment: Could it be a browser issue? Seems to work fine on Chrome 25 for Mac.

Comment: Really? Does the background disappear smoothly at the same time as the image lowers its opacity? I'm using the latest Chrome for Windows, very odd...

Comment: Works for me in Firefox 19 on Windows.

Comment: I just tested it on firefox and it does indeed work fine..... what the...

Comment: It appears to work fine in Linux Chrome 25 as well. If I had to guess what may be causing a problem, perhaps Windows Chrome doesn't like transitioning from `rgba` to `none`? Maybe instead of `none`, make it `rgba(255,255,255,0)`?

Comment: Thanks for that Jeremy, I thought that too and did test that, but same result. If I remove the img from the transition line (so just apply transition to the span) the background does disappear fine...

Comment: @Jeremy T: It actually transitions from `rgba` to `transparent` - `none` refers to the image so that stays the same throughout, and since he's using the shorthand, `transparent` is implicitly set when using `background: none`.

Comment: Just tested on Chrome 25 Win7, and everything seems to happen at the same time just like on Mac.

Comment: The background transitions fine on Chrome only when `bottom: 50px` is removed. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/kYbTp/) It looks like Chrome can't walk and chewing gum at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `span::after` to do the background and leave the `span` background transparent. Then you can use `opacity` instead of `rgba()`.

**Demo:** <sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

#### CSS:

```css
span{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:10px; 
    left:0; 
    padding:5px 10px; 
    font-size:10px;
    z-index: 1;
   }
span::after {
    background-color: white;
    content: '\A0';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: .5;
    z-index: -1;
}
img, span, span::after {
    -webkit-transition: all .8s; 
    -moz-transition: all 0.8s; 
    -ms-transition: all 0.8s; 
    -o-transition: all 0.8s; 
    transition: all .8s; 
}
div {
    position:relative;
}
div:hover span::after {
    opacity:0; 
}
div:hover span {
    bottom:50px;
}
div:hover img {
    opacity: 0.35;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    -o-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=35);
    transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
}
```

#### HTML:

```html
<div><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" />
<span>Text Text Text</span>
</div>
```

Here's another demo using a `<div>` instead of `::after`, as you mentioned having issues with that.

**Demo:** <sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

Comment: that does indeed work, the problem is that I want the letters to still show, and opacity:0 hides the letters too (that's why I was trying to do it all with RGBA) But thanks for trying!

Comment: @ThinkingStiff I know this is off topic, but how did you get that image link to the jsFiddle? I've never seen that before.

Comment: @user1202292 I figured out a way to do it while keeping the letters showing. I updated my answer and demo.

Comment: @jdwire Scroll to the bottom of the HTML section.

Comment: @ThinkingStiff I'm talking about the jsFiddle logo in your question. Is there a special way to do that, or do you just add an image and make it a link? The link back to SO from the fiddle is cool too though.

Comment: @jdwire Oh, I just created the image myself and uploaded it to SO once. I use the same link every time.

Comment: I've just noticed that the background doesn't transition though! haha, pseudo elements aren't supported to do transitions yet! (very few versions do this), so back to square 1 :( (had to remove the correct answer, sorry)

Comment: If you hove on and off very quickly you will see that the pseudo element doesn't transition, it just disappears/appears. Chrome updated this recently, but it's support by very few versions, so it might not be the best solution (it will be in a few years though)!

Comment: @user1202292 It's still working for me. Change the background to red and it's obvious. It slowly fades to nothing.

Comment: @user1202292 You can also use an empty `<div>` instead of `:after`. That was my first attempt. Here's a demo of that: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/9vRGc/

Comment: Yup! that was it, I used an empty div intead of the after, and now it's good, thanks so much!

Comment: Hey @ThinkingStiff, what's the story with your cool button integration here and on the jsfiddle? Can you point me to some doc on that stuff?

Comment: @sheriffderek No doc. I just made it myself.

Answer (score 0):

When using a transition, you have to define a beginning and an end. Instead of background none, use rgba(255,255,255,0); so the beginning and end are speaking the same language.

CSS doesn't understand things like "background-color" -> "none" for transitioning. Also, in that case, you would want to use transparent since "none" isn't valid CSS for background-color.

I Also think that maybe parts of your CSS incompatible. If you delete the scale stuff, things act as they should. Bummer. See my second fiddle, that seems to be working, so maybe you just have to write some cleaner code or something? I used figure instead of image, but it should act the same. Hope this helps!

Here is [your updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/gZyu7/), and then, [My fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/6hwb5/)

```
<figure>

    <figcaption>without scale</figcaption>

</figure>

<figure class="scale">

    <figcaption>with scale</figcaption>

</figure>
```

--

```
 .trans, figure, figcaption {

  -webkit-transition: all .5s linear; 
     -moz-transition: all .5s linear; 
       -o-transition: all .5s linear; 
          transition: all .5s linear; 
}

figure {
    position: relative;
    width: 20em;
    height: 10em;
    background-color: rgba(255,0,104,1);
}

figure:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255,0,104,.2);
}

figcaption {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0; left: 0;
    padding: 2em 1em;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
}

figure:hover figcaption {
    bottom: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.0);
}

.scale:hover {
       -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
       -moz-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
       -ms-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
       -o-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
       transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for that Derek, it is helpful, but unfortunately the problem remains. Someone else said that removing the "bottom" movement fixes it for him too, so I think chrome on windows must have some limitation somewhere with this! It's not even just the RGBA, I tested with a transparent png as background, and it's the same. But your working fiddle does work nicely..... I'm so confused!

Comment: I added an image + opacity transition to your fiddle and it breaks the background transition again (http://jsfiddle.net/6hwb5/3/).. this sucks!

Comment: OK. so... it seems to be just the opacity that is the trouble. Opacity hate the img. If you put the opacity on the div instead of the img - then it seems to work. So check this, with a .wrapper around the image.  http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/6hwb5/4/

Comment: I avoid opacity at all cost in general, it's always a pain. and it's jumpy. Depending on your use case... I often put a "cover" div over all of my images and then in your case, you could fade from rgba(255,255,255,0); -> rgba(255,255,255,.5); assuming you have a white background etc. But it's always a different solution. That is way more stable though. Opacity is a cross-browser nightmare and it looks like jumpy jQuery.

Comment: Here is that in action:  http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/6hwb5/5/  I mean, it's an extra div, but it can give you some cool added control, and if you are populating lists with php, you are really only having to add the div markup once...